# UIActivityViewController not showing all options

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

In a tableview, I am using a context menu to share a cell's image (via `snapshot()`) and a small string. However, when I use the `UIActivityViewController`, not all of the options like Mail and Messages are showing.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I show all of the share options?

```
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ResultsTableViewCell,
            let cellSnapshot = cell.snapshot() {
            let items: [Any] = ["Check out this speed test.", cellSnapshot]
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
        }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you running this on a simulator or a device?

Comment: Both. Same issue.